# Power Query - Weighted average

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

I have the following table on Power Query that contains a quantity of a product bought and his price:

[image]

I want to create another third column with the current average purchase price, however, I need to consider the history and the average should be weighted:

[image]

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Use one of the methods (easily found with a search) to create running totals of both the Quantity and Price columns.  Then divide one by the other for your weighted average

Comment: How many of these homework questions do you have? Maybe just link to the assignment?

Comment: I deleted my answer and I hope to come back as soon as possible for you.

Comment: What did you find when you did some research as to how to generate running totals, as I suggested?  How did you implement that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To calculate a running weighted average, you merely have to generate a running total cost column (Price x Quantity) and a running total quanity column, then divide one by the other:

There are various ways to do this, and you don't need to do this by adding columns to the table, but I did it so you can examine the steps involved.

#### M-Code

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Month", type text}, {"Quantity", Int64.Type}, {"Price", type number}}),
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Changed Type", "Index", 1, 1),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Cost", each [Quantity]*[Price]),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "runTotCost", each List.Sum(List.Range(#"Added Custom"[Cost],0,[Index]))),
    #"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom1", "runTotQuant", each List.Sum(List.Range(#"Added Custom"[Quantity],0,[Index]))),
    #"Added Custom3" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom2", "Weighted Average", each [runTotCost] / [runTotQuant]),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom3",{"Index", "Cost", "runTotCost", "runTotQuant"}),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Removed Columns",{{"Weighted Average", type number}})
in
    #"Changed Type1"
```

[image]

For better understanding, I suggest you do an internet search for methods of generating running totals. There are other methods that are more complicated, but more efficient.